# Tizen's virtual IME keyboard disappears

Tags: keyboard, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, enyo

I import an EnyoJS project for WebOS platform into Tizen Studio, then I ran it in a Samsung TV and there is this little problem:

When I click on a text field the virtual keyboard shows up in the TV screen, then if I click on a letter the keyboard goes down.. The letter does appear in the text field but I have to press on it again to make the keyboard shows up and press on the next letter. So I have to repeat this over and over just to write a whole word

How to fix this?

UPDATE 1:
It seems like it only happens with the `Input` kind component. I have some other panels with `TextArea` component and the keyboard works fine.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but it is likely because the Samsung virtual keyboard causes a blur event from the input, causing it to become unfocused.  Perhaps you can capture some of the events going on and diagnose the cause, then we could propose a solution.

Comment: @Pre101 I was debugging capturing events like: `keyup`, `input`, `keydown` in the web inspector right on the "Event Listener Breakpoints" drop down menu in the source tab. Strangely when using the debugger the blur event doesn't comes up..